# Python "name app = bottle.default_app() not defined" error

Tags: python, bottle

I'm using the Bottle framework for a simple application that I'm working on atm. I have my bottle library located in the folder "lib" and I call the bottle framework from the lib folder by "import lib.bottle". This is my folder structure:

```
lib
  - bottle.py
  - bottledaemon.py
  - __init__.py
view
  - log-in.tpl
mybottleapp.py
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import lib.bottle
from lib.bottle import route, template, debug, static_file, TEMPLATE_PATH, error, auth_basic, get, post, request, response, run, view, redirect, SimpleTemplate, HTTPError
from lib.bottledaemon import daemon_run
import os
import ConfigParser

#######################
#  Application Logic  #
#######################

# This line of code is not recognised:
app = bottle.default_app()

##################
#  Page Routing  #
##################

##### LOG-IN PAGE #####
@route('/')
@view('log-in')
def show_page_index():
    outout = 0

# Pathfix for Daemon mode
TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "view")))
debug(mode=True)

# Pass to the daemon
if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon_run()
```

So it throws this error at me:
"name app = bottle.default_app() not defined"

If I remove this line "app = bottle.default_app()" the app works fine BUT I realy want to have it in there for programming purposes.

So what am I doing wrong? Is it maybe cuz I run the app in daemon mode or maybe I don't call it right from the lib folder?

Btw I also can't import ConfigParser. This maybe has a diffirent cause but I can't use it.

Comment: That's not what your error message is. Give the exact message

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is change this:

```
import lib.bottle
```

to this

```
import lib.bottle as bottle
```

Note: in my setup all I need to do is this:

```
import bottle
```

Answer (score -2):

> So it throws this error at me: `name app = bottle.default_app() not defined`

### Lies

Your error is actually

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line ..., in ...
    app = bottle.default_app()
NameError: name 'bottle' is not defined
```

Because you did not define `bottle`. You defined `lib.bottle`. Either use your new name

```
app = lib.bottle.default_app()
```

or rename it:

```
import lib.bottle as bottle
```